# How can I put a number value in slide toogle Angular Material

Tags: angular, slidetoggle, angular-material2

I'd like to get all "id" from list items "checked"

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list">
   <md-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="item.id">
       item.name
    </md-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your object have any `boolean` property? Or else how would the toggle know to be checked or unchecked? If possible, add an example of `list` array, or one of its object.

Comment: The boolean is this case must to be like in condition

Comment: What do you mean by "boolean is this case must to be like in condition"?

Comment: In checkbox only send the value to server if is checked, is something like that behavior that i want in this slide toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate array that keep tracks of which item in the 'list' has been marked as `true`. Then, you can use the `change` output `event` to emit information about the `item` to your component and perform action on it.

Example code:

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">
   <md-slide-toggle [checked]="flagArray[i]"
                    (change)="sendToServer($event, i, item)">
       {{item.name}}
    </md-slide-toggle>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
flagArray = [];

  list = [
    { id: '1', name: 'item 1'},
    { id: '2', name: 'item 2'},
    { id: '3', name: 'item 3'},
    { id: '4', name: 'item 4'},
  ]

  constructor(){
    for(let  i=0; i<this.list.length; i++){
      this.flagArray.push(false);
    }
  }

  sendToServer(event, index, item){ 
    this.flagArray[index] = event.checked;

    if(event.checked == true){
      // add code to send item to server
      alert("item to send to server: " + JSON.stringify(item));        
    }
    else{
      // add code to remove item from server
      alert("item to remove from server: " + JSON.stringify(item));
    }
  }
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/BmtWM6wb9oTuyszm4tXq?p=info)